# Combine char and Vector in C++

Tags: c++, string, vector

I need to create a string that includes a vector, and I am not quite sure how I can achieve this.

My string is as follows:

```
char * cmd = "-1 $Controller SendPosition([VECOTR VALUE HERE]) \0";
```

The float that I want to insert into the string at the position [FLOAT VALUE HERE] is returned from the function:

```
object.getPosition()
```

An example of the final string that I need should look like this:

```
-1 $Controller SendPosition(43.611, 110.681, 136.22) \0
```

Comment: I dont know how to put the vector value into the string

Comment: point 1) that thing is not a string in C++.

Comment: @LeoZhuang - Not really a C++ solution

Comment: for pure C++ solution, `std::stringstream`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use stringstream to concat strings and values.

```
#include <sstream>

std::stringstream ss;

ss << "-1 $Controller SendPosition(" << vec[0];
for( size_t i=1; i<vec.size(); i++ ) ss << ", " << vec[i] ;
ss << ")";

cout << ss.str();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
   std::vector<char> v;

   ...  Add to vector

   std::string s("-1 $Controller SendPosition([");
   s += v.front();
   s += "])";
```